# IntelliJ IDEA - Change Reveal In Finder to a new file browser

Tags: macos, intellij-idea, jetbrains-ide, path-finding

I have set up *Path Finder* as my default file browser(manager) on my OSX Yosemite. So most applications open a Path Finder window when they show me a File, but not IDEA.

When I choose the `Reveal in Finder` action on a file it always opens a new finder window, which is kind of annoying because copying from a Path Finder window to a Finder window is not working.

Is there any way to tell IntelliJ IDEA to use Path Finder?

Comment: I think that this is not configurable (as far as I know this action always uses system default file manager). Isn't there a way to set Pathfinder as default file manager instead of Finder in OS X? (I'm not using Mac, so I don't know).

Comment: @BohuslavBurghardt Pathfinder is set as default file manager. And if I tell an other application to reveal a file in finder, it uses Pathfinder. I just doesn't work in IDEA...

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a new **external tool** and then add it to the relevant context menu.

Go to `Settings | Tools | External Tools` and click the `+` button to create a new one:

[image]

Set a name for your tool like *Show In Thunar* and then in the program section, you must insert the command that can open the installed file explorer. In my case, I inserted thunar (make sure about the command via terminal). And **do not** forget to set `$FileDir$` as the `arguments`.

After creating your tool you can add it to your context menu, for doing this go to `Appearance & Behavior | Menus and Toolbars | Project View Popup Menu > Project View Popup Menu Run Group > Run Configurations > RevealGroup`

[image]

Click the `Add After` button and select the new external tools that you have created in the early stage.