# How to "Show in Explorer" / "Reveal in Finder" in PhpStorm?

Tags: phpstorm, finder, windows-explorer

In PhpStorm, is there a way to show a file in [Windows Explorer (for Windows)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_Explorer) or [Finder (for Mac)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finder_(software))?

Even better, is it possible to add such an option in the menu when I right click on a tab?

Do I need a plugin for that?

Comment: What do you mean by "Open in Explorer" exactly? Show current file in your explorer .. or open that file using default program? Or maybe something else?

Comment: In the file browser, right click on a directory or file and click on *Show on Files* (the last word can be different on your OS).

Comment: I meant - show in explorer. That function exists in project section, you can right click on file or directory and in drop-down menu choose show in exprorer and directory of file will be opened in windows explorer, I need the same function in tabs.

Comment: Yes, I need Show on Files in right click in tabs ...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can always use `Navigate | Select in... | Show in Explorer` (<kbd>Alt + F1, 8</kbd> using Default keymap) for that.

Same shortcut will work from other places (e.g. Project View panel etc).

---

If you still want to add context menu item .. then you can do that in `Settings/Preferences | Appearance & Behaviour | Menus & Toolbars --> Editor Tab Popup Menu`. The actual action is called `Show in Explorer`

Comment: And if you need to use another `file browser` or add a new one check this link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66384313/3881354

Answer (score 0):

I don't find any plugins for do that.
Perhaps because this is a simple function which can launch/call easily with a simple shortcut keyboard.

File > Settings > Keymap > 'explorer' > Other > Show in Explorer.
Add shortcut for this function and you can open a new explorer OS in a same directory that your file is.

Perhaps if I don't understand "Open in Explorer" you can also easily point your view 'project' in a exact directory where is your file is.

For that I assign a shortcut in a function named 'Select In'. With this a menu appear and I can select lot of function and one for target project View directly where is my file active in editor (very useful).